# How do you make a tab bar where it will not mess up your views

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, tabbar

I have tried multiple different ways to make a tab bar but for some reason, it messes up my views either preventing them from scrolling or their functionality completely corrupts here are two of the ways I tried why is this happening? They both allow me to switch between views but they bot alter the functionality or the performance of my views and it is confusing as to why it should just go from one view to the other no problem.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Home: View {
    
    @State var selectedTab = "Global"
    var edges = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
        ZStack(alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .center, vertical: .bottom)) {
           
            ZStack{
                
                SettingsView()
                    .opacity(selectedTab == "Settings" ? 1 : 0)
                
                Ether()
                    .opacity(selectedTab == "Ether" ? 1 : 0)
                
                PostView()
                    .opacity(selectedTab == "Global" ? 1 : 0)
                
                
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
            CustomTabbar(selectedTab: $selectedTab)
                .padding(.bottom,edges!.bottom == 0 ? 15 : 0)
        }
       .background(Color(.black).ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .all))
        
        .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .bottom)
        
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        
    }
    }
}

import SwiftUI

struct Home: View {
    
   // @State var selectedTab = "Global"
    var edges = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets
    
    var body: some View {
        
        TabView {
            
            PostView()
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "flame")
                Text("Global")
            }
                Ether()
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "flame.fill")
                Text("Ether")
            }
            SettingsView()
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "person")
                Text("Profile")
            }
        }
    }
}



import SwiftUI

struct CustomTabbar: View {
    @Binding var selectedTab : String
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack(spacing: 0){
            
            TabButton(title: "Global", selectedTab: $selectedTab)
            
            TabButton(title: "Ether", selectedTab: $selectedTab)
            
            TabButton(title: "Settings", selectedTab: $selectedTab)
            
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .background(Color.white)
        .clipShape(Capsule())
        
    }
    
}
struct TabButton : View {
    
    var title : String
    @Binding var selectedTab : String
    
    var body: some View{
        
        Button(action: {selectedTab = title}) {
            
            VStack(spacing: 5){
                
                Image(title)
                    .renderingMode(.template)
                
                Text(title)
                    .font(.caption)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                
                    .foregroundColor(selectedTab == title ? Color(.blue) : .gray)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .padding(.vertical,10)
                    
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show code for `CustomTabbar`? Also it would be helpful if you posted a screenshot of the differences

Comment: @aheze I have complied with your request and uploaded the custom tab bar as requested.

Comment: Your code runs fine for me

Comment: @aheze do you have a scroll view in the postview and ether?

Comment: Ah no, I forgot about that

Comment: Alright, added a scroll view, looks fine

Comment: @aheze yes the issue isn't the tab bar not working it is the fact it's affecting all types of other features in my app that arent part of the tab. like the post view by itself functions fine. Then I put the basic tab bar and now the scroll is going over the hstack. or when I clock a button on the ether view nothing appears. if I use the the custom tab bar version then the post view works fine but the ether doesen't scroll and the buttons don't function right either